# Why is my download speed 10X slower than my upload?

Tags: wireless-networking, download, desktop-computer, upload, internet-speed

Screenshot of speedtest:

[image: Screenshot of speedtest]

I am confused at what is wrong. I have AT&T Fiber 300 Mbps internet but only was getting about 30 Mbps upload and download over Wifi. Then I went out and bought a 100 ft Cat 6 cord and connected directly to my router to my PC and now am getting 300 Mbps upload and still only 30 Mbps download. (See picture). FYI I am using and older desktop PC with Windows 10 Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3330 CPU @ 3.00GHz   3.00 GHz Installed Ram: 8.00 GB (7.87 GB usable) and System: 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor.

What is going wrong? Any ideas of how I can fix this problem?

Thanks for your time, much appreciated.

Comment: Complain to AT&T, either they have configured it wrongly or the backend line is severely over provisioned.

Comment: You can try rebooting the modem and router _(unplug both, leave unplugged for 10min to ensure memory is cleared, plug modem in and wait for it to fully boot (~60 - 90s), then plug in the router)_, however if that doesn't resolve it, the issue is likely on AT&T's side as @Bib mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the response but that solution did not work. I did exactly what you said but still have less than 40 Mbps download and over 300 Mbps upload.

Comment: I will add that before connecting the Cat 6 they were both less than 40 Mbps via Wife. Is there something with my older PC that I need to update or correct?

Comment: I don't think it can be AT&T bc when I test the speed on my cell I get over 300 Mbps upload and over 300 Mbps download